# Where can I find a software library for pairwise matching (ideally, Python, R, Java)?

Tags: machine-learning, python, r

I am looking for a library that implements a pairwise ranking algorithm. For example, if I have 200 writing samples from 100 people (two samples from each individual) and I want to identify which samples belong together (i.e., were written by the same person), what library could I use?

Comment: Do you have details about the number of samples written by a single person? Is it 200 together or by each?

Comment: It is 200 together (i.e., two samples per person).

Comment: Do you just want a person to handwriting match? Or a ranking giving the highest priority to the ones with the maximum match?

Comment: Just a match. E.g, if I have person_1_writing_sample_1, person_1_writing_sample_2, person_2_writing_sample_1, and person_2_writing_sample_2, I want to match the two former and the two latter.

Comment: Try k-means with 100 clusters. You should be able to find a library for it in every language.

Comment: I hasten to add that you can't run a clustering algorithm (like k-means) with free-form text; you need to featurize it first, and you want [stylometric features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stylometry) in particular. See e.g. [Using Machine Learning Techniques for Stylometry](http://www2.tcs.ifi.lmu.de/~ramyaa/publications/stylometry.pdf), [Conversationally-inspired Stylometric Features for Authorship Attribution in Instant Messaging](http://www.dcs.gla.ac.uk/~vincia/papers/stylometry-MM-2012.pdf) or [Adversarial Stylometry](https://www.cs.drexel.edu/~sa499/papers/adversarial_stylometry.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can transform those sentences into number vectors (e.g. into a [bag of words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model) or [tf-idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf-idf) representation), I guess you could use k-Means or hierarchical clustering functionality from [Orange](http://orange.biolab.si/), a GUI and machine learning library written in Python.

It also has an [add-on for text mining](https://github.com/biolab/orange3-text/) specifically, but I cannot attest to it as I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Thanks. Ultimately, I decided to go with difference metrics (Jaccard, etc.).